# Different pointer address printed inside function

Tags: c, pointers

I am new to C and pointers. The following is some code that i was experimenting with.

```
struct node{
    struct node * next;
    struct node * prev;
    int num;
 };

 void func(struct node * leaf , struct node ** add_leaf){
     printf("function starts");
     printf("&leaf = %p  add_leaf = %p\n" , &leaf , add_leaf);
     printf("leaf = %p  *add_leaf = %p\n" , leaf , *add_leaf);
     printf("function over");
     return
 }


 void main(){
     struct node * leaf = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
     printf("leaf = %p\t&leaf = %p\n" , leaf , &leaf);
     func(leaf , &leaf);
 }
```

The values of leaf and *add_leaf are equal and that was what i expected. However I could not
understand why was there a difference in the values of &leaf and add_leaf when printed inside the function. Here, I am trying to print the address of the node pointer leaf.

Comment: thanks, made the change

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The local variable `leaf` in the `main` is copied when `func` is invoked. This means, the local variable `leaf` inside `func` has the same value as `leaf` inside `main`, i.e. it points to the same memory address (thus equivalence for the second check), but it is itself stored at a different address.

Comment: ... with the net effect that parameters become local variables. So if you wanted to treat one as what many other languages call an `inout` or similar — as something you could modify and have that modification affect the values supplied in the calling scope — you'd need to add an extra level of indirection and modify via a pointer reference. That's (partly) why your code is taking `leaf` as a pointer: so it can modify the thing pointed to such that the modifications are more than local and transient.

Answer (score 2):

I usually find it easier to understand pointers if you draw a picture with arrows and  boxes.

**&leaf** gives you the address of the varible **leaf**, and since you have two different variables named **leaf** (both containing pointers to your malloc-allocated struct), you get two different addresses:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`leaf` is a pointer to a `struct node`, and a pointer is a 32 bit (depending on architecture) integer that is stored somewhere in memory.

When you pass `leaf` to `printf`, what happens is, a copy of the `leaf` variable will be made on the stack. That copy corresponds to the 2nd local argument of `printf` function.

But when you pass `&leaf` to the `printf` function, what you do is you pass the *address* of the `leaf` variable.

Since the `leaf` variable in `main()` and the 2nd argument of `printf` are in two different locations, it will indeed print two memory addresses.